# What does JettyConnectionMetrics count?

Tags: jetty, micrometer

The Micrometer library has a `JettyConnectionMetrics` class which produces these metrics (among others):

```
# HELP jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes Bytes received by tracked connections
# TYPE jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes summary
jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes_count 125.0
jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes_sum 186955.0
# HELP jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes_max Bytes received by tracked connections
# TYPE jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes_max gauge
jetty_connections_bytes_in_bytes_max 1681.0
```

What does this actually count? What does tracked mean here?

If I add it to our (only one) connector will it contain every bytes received by the TCP connection?

I am right that it is updated only on connection close which could delay data when there is a HAProxy between real clients and Jetty (with keep-alive connections)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this actually count?

According to the [code of this class](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jetty/JettyConnectionMetrics.java), it measure the following points:

- Messages received by tracked connections
- Messages sent by tracked connections
- Bytes received by tracked connections
- Bytes sent by tracked connections
- The maximum number of observed connections over a rolling 2-minute interval
- The current number of open Jetty connections

> What does tracked mean here?

Because `JettyConnectionMetrics` is [Jetty's `Connection.Listener`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/io/Connection.Listener.html), when registered into a `Connector`, it'll track all `open` and `close` events, i.e. whenever an I/O event occurs on that connector.

> If I add it to our (only one) connector will it contain every bytes received by the TCP connection?

Yes, if you are using [`ServerConnector`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.5.v20170502/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html), that is the primary connector for the Jetty server over TCP/IP.

> I am right that it is updated only on connection close which could delay data when there is a HAProxy between real clients and Jetty (with keep-alive connections)?

Yes, you're right, that is updated only when a connection closes. Depending how is this important for your metrics, you may consider disabling `keep-alive` connections and require always that connections get closed (make sure you understand the trade-offs of this change).